# Compile .tex file to a pdf on os X

Tags: installing, mac

I installed mactex and I wrote a resume in Vim, but I can't figure out how to compile the .tex file into a pdf using the command line.  I have a program called TexWorks that does it, but I'm more comfortable just using the command line.

How does one compile .tex to .pdf?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `pdflatex <filename>`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you installed TeX with the MacTeX installer, you have just to type `pdflatex filename` in a Terminal window. It's not different from any other Unix system.

Comment: just try `xelatex <filename>` it would work even if you have just installed BasicTex

Comment: If you just installed MacTeX via Homebrew you will need to restart your shell if you are using the command line (at least I needed to)

Comment: Just `optex <filename>` if you are using OpTeX for converting .tex file to PDF.

Answer (score 29):

### El Capitan and Later

Changes [related to El Capitan](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/mac-os-changes-that-affect-lots-of-answers) mean the solution below will not work.

### Before MacOS *El Capitan*

The MacTeX installer makes a soft link

```
/usr/texbin
```

pointing to the directory containing the binaries relative to the current release of TeX Live (although in a somewhat indirect way). On my system, if I try `ls -l /usr/texbin`, I get

```
/usr/texbin@ -> /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin
```

where `/Library/TeX/` contains a clever set of soft links. At the end of the story, `/usr/texbin` points to

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

If you have multiple TeX distributions (or want to switch to the `universal-darwin` binaries, you can use the “TeX Distribution” panel in the System Preferences application.

The MacTeX installer also adds a file called `TeX` in `/etc/paths.d` that contains the single line `/usr/texbin`, so that this directory will be included in the `PATH` environment variable.

All the above amounts to saying that you simply issue, on a Terminal window, the command

```
pdflatex <filename>
```

in order to compile the LaTeX file. Change the engine using `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: UPDATE. On more recent versions, `/usr/texbin` is not used any longer, but the links are to `/Library/TeX/texbin`; the mechanism is the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Using pdflatex

The command I am using frequently is

```bash
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode file_name.tex
```

The flag `-interaction=STRING` is to keep on compile the pdf even if there is an error, we set the `STRING` with one of the options from the interaction mode (`STRING=batchmode/nonstopmode/scrollmode/errorstopmode`)

- This is extremely useful in a batch mode or as part of an automated process because it can hang indefinitely waiting for user input.
- pdflatex will not stop on errors. Instead, it will automatically try to recover and continue processing the rest of the document.

Comment: But it should be noted that if there is an error in the compilation, the resulting pdf can only be used as a guide to locate the error.

Comment: I apologize, I shared this as I use it as part of an automated process, such as in a continuous integration (CI) pipeline, the nonstop mode is invaluable. In automated settings, you don't have the luxury to manually intervene and address each error interactively. Especially in report generation task. 
but maybe I'm wrong!